# Is there a difference between an 'app' and a 'software'

Tags: language

Is there a difference between an 'app' and a 'software'? My latest Windows asked me if i wanted to download an 'app' but it seems like a software, wondering if there is a difference between the two beyond a marketing one.

Comment: Application software (an application) is a set of computer programs designed to permit the user to perform a group of coordinated functions, tasks, or activities. Application software cannot run on itself but is dependent on system software to execute. Program- A set of instructions telling a computer what to do.

Comment: [same thing to all intents & purposes at user-level] Program - Windows terminology. Application - Apple terminology. App [abbreviation] - Apple terminology initially, now borrowed by everyone else 'cos Prog just doesn't sound as 'cool'.

Comment: Here's a [similar question](https://support.google.com/chromebook/thread/152056048?hl=en) I had posted in regards to the CrOS platform you may find to be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Why not consult [a dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/app)!

> ### app
>
> #### noun
>
> 1 *Computing*
>       An application, especially as downloaded by a user to a mobile device.
>
> > ‘I've just installed the app on my phone’

So, an app is an application. It’s of course also software. In the context of full-fledged computer it could refer to small, single-purpose applications or applications downloaded from a built-in “App Store”.